# Slack: Retrieve all messages

Tags: slack-api

I want to retrieve all the messages that were sent in my teams slack domain. Although, I'd prefer that the data be received in XML or JSON I am able to handle the data in just about any form.

How can I retrieve all these messages? Is it possible? If not, can I retrieve all the messages for a specific channel?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you need to do this dynamically via API you can use the [channels.list method](https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.list) to list all of the channels in your team and [channels.history method](https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.history) to retrieve the history of each channel. Note that this will not include DMs or private groups.

If you need to do this as a one time thing, go to https://my.slack.com/services/export to export your team's message archives as series of JSON files

[image: message archive export screen]

Comment: It seem like only admins can export via the [link](https://my.slack.com/services/export), can I as a member export the channel as well?

Comment: @seanrose, Is there a way to click to that page?

Answer (score 14):

This Python script exports everything to JSON by a simple run:
https://gist.github.com/Chandler/fb7a070f52883849de35

It creates the directories for you and you have the option to exclude direct messages or channels.

All you need to install is the slacker module, which is simply `pip install slacker`. Then run it with `--token='secret-token'`. You need a legacy token, which is available [here](https://api.slack.com/custom-integrations/legacy-tokens) at the moment.

Comment: works well, except `429 Client Error: Too Many Requests for url: <omitted>`

Comment: Legacy tokens are no longer available if you don't already have one.

Answer (score 11):

For anyone looking for Direct Message history downloads, [this](https://github.com/hisabimbola/slack-history-export) node based cli tool allows you to download messages from DMs and IMs in both JSON and CSV. I've used it, and it works very well.

Comment: Links tend to change or go missing, could you explain some of the contents or quote it here?

Comment: @abarisone The tool is called `slack-history-export` and can be installed with `npm install -g slack-history-export`. See options with `slack-history-export -h`.

Comment: This requires a Legacy Token, which are no longer available if you don't already have one.

Answer (score 7):

With the new [Conversations API](https://api.slack.com/docs/conversations-api) this task is bit easier now. Here is a full overview:

**Fetching messages from a channel**

The new API method [`conversations.history`](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.history) will allow you to download messages from every type of conversation / channel (public, private, DM, Group DM) as long as your token has access to it.

This method also supports paging allowing you to download large amounts of messages.

**Resolving IDs to names**

Note that this method will return messages in a raw JSON format with IDs only, so you will need to call additional API method to resolve those IDs into plain text:

- user ID: [`users.list`](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.list)
- channel IDs: [`conversations.list`](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.list)
- bot IDs: [`bots.info`](https://api.slack.com/methods/bots.info) (there is no official `bots.list` method, but there is an [unofficial one](https://github.com/ErikKalkoken/slackApiDoc/blob/master/bots.list.md), which might help in some cases)

**Fetching threads**

In addition use [conversations.replies](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.replies) to download threads in a conversation. Threads function a bit like conversations within a conversation and need to be downloaded separately.

Check out [this page](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-threading) of the official documentation for more details on threading.

Comment: Interested to know - how would I grant access to all private/group DM channels via my token?

Comment: You can't. Slack's security architecture won't allow it.

Comment: That's a pain. I've already +1'd but it'd be nice to add that to your answer.

Comment: Its my understanding this question is about public channels only. As you can see from the accepted answer it does not include private channels. Check this answer on how to get access to all private channels: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53142640/4379151

Answer (score 4):

If anyone is still looking for a solution in 2021, and of course have no assistance from their workspace admins to export messages then obviously they can do the following.

Step 1:  Get the api token from your UI cookie

- Clone and install requirements and run [SlackPirate](https://github.com/emtunc/SlackPirate)
- Open slack on a browser and copy the value of the cookie named `d`
- Run `python3 SlackPirate.py --cookie '<value of d cookie>'`

Step 2:  Dump the channel messages

- Install [slackchannel2pdf](https://github.com/ErikKalkoken/slackchannel2pdf) (Requires python)
- `slackchannel2pdf --token 'xoxb-1466...' --write-raw-data  T0EKHQHK2/G015H62SR3M`

Step 3: Dump the direct messages

- Install [slack-history-export](https://github.com/hisabimbola/slack-history-export) (Requires node)
- `slack-history-export -t 'xoxs-1466...' -u '<correct username>' -f 'my_colleagues_chats.json'`

Comment: `slackchannel2pdf` with the `--write-raw-data` flag does what I wanted. I did `pip install pdf2text` then use `pdf2text` to convert the PDF file to plain and so far that works well. No weird artifacts from PDF conversion that I can see.

Comment: Hi, when i am trying to get the cookie value and run the python3 command i keep getting the error No Workspaces were found with this cookie. To retreive the value, i went to inspect element -> storage -> cookies and retrieved the value of "d". Any ideas on what could be causing the issue?

Comment: Did you check the recent issues of https://github.com/emtunc/SlackPirate ? 
May be this has came up recently with slack's api changes.

Answer (score 4):

I know that this might be late for the OP, but if anyone is looking for a tool capable of doing the full Slack Workspace export, try [Slackdump](https://github.com/rusq/slackdump) it's free and open source (I'm the author, but anyone can contribute).

To do the workspace export, run it with `-export` switch:

```bash
./slackdump -export my_export.zip
```

If you need to download attachments as well, use the `-f` switch (stands for "files"):

```bash
./slackdump -f -export my_export.zip
```

It will open the browser asking you to login.  If you need to do it headless, grab a token and cookie, as described in the [documentation](https://github.com/rusq/slackdump/blob/master/doc/login-manual.rst)

It will generate the export file that would be compatible with another nice tool [slack-export-viewer](https://github.com/hfaran/slack-export-viewer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is another tool for exporting all messages from a channel.

The tool is called [slackchannel2pdf](https://github.com/ErikKalkoken/slackchannel2pdf) and will export all messages from a public or private channel to a PDF document.

You only need a token with the required scopes and access.

Comment: Downvoted for PDF. Why that format of all formats?!?

Comment: @NoahSussman The purpose of exporting a channel is usually so that you can archive it or send it by email. PDF allows you to render the complete content of a channel in a single file and is widely supported across many platforms, e.g. every browser supports it. So I think it is a good choice, but if you disagree what other format would you suggest and why?

Comment: Why not a plain text format like JSON?

Comment: Ok now I see it does do JSON with the `--write-raw-data` flag. That's cool! It is a good tool and I would take back my downvote if I could. However you should consider changing the name to emphasize it can download json AND PDF both. Because a lot of people are like me and don't trust the PDF format. Also fwiw consider an HTML output option?

Comment: I have upvoted it for you.

Answer (score 0):

In order to retrieve all the messages from a particular channel in slack this can be done by using [conversations.history](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.history) method in `slack_sdk` library in python.

```
def get_conversation_history(self, channel_id, latest, oldest):
        """Method to fetch the conversation history of particular channel"""
        try:
            result = client.conversations_history(
                channel=channel_id,
                inclusive=True,
                latest=latest,
                oldest=oldest,
                limit=100)
            all_messages = []
            all_messages += result["messages"]
            ts_list = [item['ts'] for item in all_messages]
            last_ts = ts_list[:-1]
            while result['has_more']:
                result = client.conversations_history(
                    channel=channel_id,
                    cursor=result['response_metadata']['next_cursor'],
                    latest=last_ts)
                all_messages += result["messages"]
            return all_messages
        except SlackApiError as e:
            logger.exception("Error while fetching the conversation history")
```

Here, i have provided latest and oldest timestamps to cover a time range when we need to collect the messages from the all messages in conversation history.

And the cusor argument is being used to point the next cursor value as this method can only collect 100 messages at one time but it supports [pagination](https://api.slack.com/docs/pagination) through which we can point the next cursor value from `result['response_metadata']['next_cursor']`.

Hope this will be helpful.