# Convert Slack Export to CSV in C#

Tags: c#, slack-api, slack

How would I go about converting a Slack export exported by something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28818809/slack-retrieve-all-messages) to a format like CSV?  I've been provided a few raw exports, but need to provide something that can be used to review the chats' content.  Ideally the final output could be reviewed in something like Excel or a text editor.

Comment: https://json-csv.com/

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that there are potentially thousands of these exports that need to be converted.  Additionally, due to data privacy, the data can't be converted by a web service.

Comment: The second answer to the question you linked mentions a library that can export the data as csv. Can you use that? http://stackoverflow.com/a/35286207/2428407

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have the ability to re-export the data in a different format.  All I have at this point is the exported Json.