# Slack API client for push notification

Tags: node.js, push-notification, chat, slack, slack-api

I'm building a Slack (instant messaging) chat client, I'm looking for a way to trigger a notification to receipent when a new message is sent to him, push notification of course.

What's the endpoint or stream API to be able to trigger a push notification to devices?

I think it should be some backend microservice listening for incoming messages in a channel with a list for users to notify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get instant notifications about new messages posted to a channel you can either use the Real Time Messaging API (RTM API) or the Events API.

The main difference:

- [RTM API](https://api.slack.com/rtm) uses Websockets and you will receive a constant stream of events about everything that happens on the connected workspace.
- [Events API](https://api.slack.com/events) uses standard HTTP requests and Slack will only send events to your endpoint that you subscribed too.

There are many factors to consider when choosing the right API for a project. Please also see the official [FAQ](https://api.slack.com/faq#events_api) from Slack on the topic for more details.

Comment: My personal opinion: Try to use Events API. It is much easier to implement and use, since you don't need to bother with Websockets and it can be integrated with a standard Slack app.

Comment: I was looking "message" event docs and not all informations are self contained into the payload. So maybe i need to store users of each channel or better implement a pub/sub to trigger the push notification to all receipents. What do you think?

Comment: yes, you will get IDs only for most objects in the message events. Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28818809/slack-retrieve-all-messages/53103251#53103251) on how to get the missing info. They have rate limits so you want to collect them rarely if possible.

Comment: Cool reference! In the meantime I try to figure out how organize my architecture and how get user and channel name info to build a rich notification text I’ll mark your answer as correct. Thanks so much :)